# Why do I keep getting this error in my code?

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to do a partial matching on my data using the `UTL_MATCH`, what am I doing wrong?

```
SELECT 
    col1, col2,
    UTL_MATCH.edit_distance(col1, col2) AS ed
FROM 
    match_tab
ORDER BY 
    id;
```

Expected the partial match but instead, I am getting the error message below

> Msg 4121, Level 16, State 1, Line 3 Cannot find either column
>   "UTL_MATCH" or the user-defined function or aggregate
>   "UTL_MATCH.edit_distance", or the name is ambiguous.

Comment: Add some sample data and expected results.

Comment: Is this Oracle or have you rolled your own utl_match in sqlserver?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like an error of Sql-Server (you are probably connected to a sql-server session),it does not return an error of type ORA-xxx.

You should try this example and it must work

```
SELECT UTL_MATCH.EDIT_DISTANCE('shackleford', 'shackelford') FROM DUAL;  
-------------
returns 2
```